# GET a form.jsp with ajax and a param inside

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

Is it possible to print a param (with jstl) given by a servlet in a form.jsp brought by ajax in index.jsp ?

For example,

index.jsp

```
<div class='show'>
    <div class='show-content'></div>
</div>
${name}
```

form.jsp

```
<form action='servlet'>
    ${name}
    //inputs and a button
</form>
```

servlet.java

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        String s = "Jean";
        request.setAttribute("name", s);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

script.js

```
function openContentFrom(tag, path){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", path, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState === 4){
        if (xhr.status === 200){
            var txt = xhr.responseText;
            var trueTxt = txt.substr(txt.indexOf("<" + tag + ">") + 6, txt.indexOf("</" + tag + ">"));
            document.getElementsByClassName("show-content")["0"].innerHTML = trueTxt;
        }
        else{
            console.log("Error : " + xhr.status);
        }
    }
};
xhr.send(this);
}

openContentFrom("body", "form.jsp");
```

So here, a script.js will bring content of form.jsp inside show-content in index.jsp when called with ajax, and if the servlet has already been executed, it would print Jean in both form.jsp and index.jsp.

For now, with get and post it is not possible (well it just prints Jean on index.jsp of course) and i wonder if it is, because i searched and didn't find yet.

Content of request in servlet is posted back to index.jsp i guess, so can I send it back to form.jsp ?

Thanks !

Comment: It's a little bit confusing. Please try to explain what you want to achieve. Why don't you simply send the name as JSON from the servlet call?

Comment: I'll see what I can do. Will it stay in memory for the whole page ?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to return a form

on your servlet remove those 2 lines

```
request.setAttribute("name", s);
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and add

```
response.getWriter().write(s);
```

on your ajax

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(s){
    alert(s);
}
```